# Parsha reading gap between Israel and overseas

Tags: halacha, parsha-torah-portion

The 7th of Pesach this year was celebrated in Israel on Friday, and overseas on Friday and Saturday.
This caused a discrepancy in Parsha reading between overseas and Israel, since outside Israel the reading for Pesach took the place of the reading for shabas.
If someone flies from Israel abroad (and vice versa) and will be there on Sabbath,
he hears a Parsha he had heard before (or in the second case misses a Parsha).

The discrepancy this year persists between 14th April and 19th May (Leminyanam).

What is the solution for such a person in Halacha?

Is The Halacha recommended to not enter to this situations ?

I read along time ago in Yalkut Yosef that Harav Ovadia had similar situation and when he comes back to Israel, he recived first Aliya to the Torah, and they read for him the previous Parasha and the First Aliya for the current Parasha, but this could be an option only for Harav Ovadia (or another respectable Rabbi) that the audience accorded respect.

Comment: The tekana is to have 7 call ups each week.  Why do you have to hear it from the scroll in order?  2 mikra 1 targum is different.  They used to do the torah every 3 years.  So You'll hear all the parshas within 3 years.  Solution to what problem do you want?

Comment: You first have to demonstrate a problem before asking for a solution.

Comment: In Israel it's not hard to find American minyanim that will read the parsha according to the diaspora sequence. In the US such a minyan will probably only be found in very large cities.

Comment: Similar: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/95735/170

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Rema ([Orach Chayim 135:2](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%94_%D7%91)) rules that a synagogue that missed kriat hatorah one week is required to make it up the following week. The first oleh reads the entire previous parsha (the one the synagogue missed) plus the first aliyah of this week's parsha, and from the second aliyah on, the aliyot of this week's parsha are divided as normal.

[Halacha Berurah](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/285/69) Orach Chaim 135:9 writes that when an Israeli misses a parsha becuase of the different calendars, **if the tzibbur agrees** they can call this Israeli for the first aliyah to read the entire previous parsha (the one he missed) plus the first aliyah of this week's parsha. However, he points out that since kriat hatorah is not a mitzvah on each individual, rather it's a mitzvah on the tzibur, making up for a parsha that you missed is not required unless the synagogue missed kriat hatorah.

So in Rav Ovadia's case, his congregation probably consented to read the parsha he missed to honor him. I don't know about what Rav Ovadia's minyan was like at the time of the incident described in Yalkut Yosef, but these days, Rav Ovadia's minyan is "Rav Ovadia's minyan" -- it's in a beit kenesset attached to his apartment in Har Nof, and the beit kenesset exists only by virtue of the fact that Rav Ovadia davens there. Consequently there's a lot of deference to his personal needs and personal honor.