# What should a community do if they missed a Parsha?

Tags: halacha, torah-reading

A shul 500 miles away from civilization had its only Sefer Torah stolen on Shabbos morning. As such, they couldn't read the parsha.

By the next week, they got themselves a new Sefer Torah.

Do they read a double parsha or do they just skip it and move on?

Comment: I dont have the source offhand, but is seems obvious that they must read the missed parsha. The original takkana of kriyas hatorah was to finish the Torah. By skipping a parsha one fails the takkana. The only need to read two parhiyos the next week would be to conform to the general minhag of finishing the Torah every year. It should be noted that this is not an absolute obligation. See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53057/are-there-any-leniencies-for-shortening-the-torah-reading-so-the-cycle-takes-mor

Comment: The Rama ([OC 135:2](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%94#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.91)) indicates that they read both portions on the following Shabbos.

Comment: Note that the same question applies when traveling between Eretz Yisrael and Chutz La'aretz when the parsha of the week differ (as happened this year). That is, a full minyon tour group and not an individual.

Comment: Could also be the case that the only sefer torah is Pasul and so they can't read from it and by next week it has been rectified.

Although if you find that a sefer torah is pasul it doesn't invalidate previous readings from it, i.e. you don't have to read them all again. (That would be a problem!)

Comment: .... and improve the security around the Aron Kodesh!

Comment: @Fred Why not post an answer?

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16303/parsha-reading-gap-between-israel-and-overseas

Comment: related (or dupe?): https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/91671/shul-closed-for-a-shabbos-do-they-have-to-repeat-the-missed-sedrah-when-they-ge/91672#91672 In the text, this question focuses on a 'bediavad' case while the other question is less so, but in theory almost any answer to either question will answer the other

Answer (score 1):

The tzibbur should make up the lost parsha.  However there is no obligation on individual members of the congregation to make up the parsha.  Thus, those who were in chutz laAretz for Pesach this year and then returned to Israel after Pesach, would not have to find a shul that would lein the parsha that they had missed.  For good sources see this article:http://ohr.edu/this_week/insights_into_halacha/5130

Comment: Thanks for not just this answer, but answering a side question that I was curious about, in your 2nd sentence. That situation happened to one of my relatives.

Comment: "This shittah is obviously not like the Maharam Mintz, who maintains that we never read more than two Parshiyos together, even if it will cause one to miss out hearing a parshah b’tzibbur. Although several poskim, including the Kenesses Hagedolah, the Olas Tamid, Ateres Zekeinim and Ba’er Heitiv, rule this way, nevertheless, the halacha seems to follow the Haghos HaMinhagim, the Elyah Rabbah, Magen Giborim, and Aruch Hashulchan who strongly argue that there is no reason not to allow a catching up of several parshiyos as long as it is done along with reading the correct Parshah of that week."