# Shul closed for a Shabbos. Do they have to repeat the missed sedrah when they get back?

Tags: halacha, synagogue, torah-reading

The Rema paskens in [O Ch 135 (2)](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.135.2?lang=bi&with=Mishnah%20Berurah&lang2=en)

> If they neglected [to be able to hold] the public reading of the
>   parashah, then for the following Shabbat they read that parashah (i.e.
>   the missed one) along with the parashah belonging to that (i.e. the
>   following) Shabbat (Or Zarua).

Say the Congregation closes down for a Shabbos;  the members went on private holidays in numerous areas with minyonim and heard the leining where they were. When they return to their regular shul building, are they required to make up the reading or not? In other words is the sedrah reading an obligation on the congregation or on the shul building? 
 
It seems obvious to me that it is an obligation on the congregation but my Chavrusah disagrees.

Comment: To clarify the case, did literally every person go elsewhere? Is there even one person who stayed home didn't hear the missed week? Is there maybe a mere 6 or 10 who didn't hear the missed week?

Comment: I remember learning that Rav Moshe held krias HaTorah is an indvidual obligation which is considered the novel approach. While the mainstream hold its a communal obligation

Comment: @sam while that's the rumor on the street my understanding is that both of r moshes sons deny he held that way

Comment: Yes @DoubleAA...  literally every person went elsewhere. The Shul was closed for that Shabbos.

Comment: Really? From what I was told by ppl from MTJ was that Rav Moshe was makpid to hear krias haTorah even when he couldnt daven with minyan.

Comment: @sam I have no solid proof either way. Just "Shmuos"

Comment: @OP was i totally off?

Comment: @aBochur I upvoted your answer. My Chavrusa regards the term "Bemeizid" as somewhat strong for the case we have - but it's certainly not "Beshogeg"!

Comment: I think this Q was already asked here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/61197/what-should-a-community-do-if-they-missed-a-parsha

Answer (score 0):

There answer is no, they do not read it again:

From the Biur Halacha [135:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Biur_Halacha.135.2.1)

> אם בטלו וכו' - עיין מ"ב ועיין בעט"ז דמסתפק אם דוקא בשוגג או אפילו במזיד נמי צריך להשלים ובפמ"ג ובשלחן עצי שטים כתבו דמסתימת הפוסקים משמע דאפילו במזיד נמי משלימין אכן מביאור הגר"א דנסיב טעמא דהאי דינא מדין תפלה דקיי"ל טעה ולא התפלל איזה תפלה משלים אותה בתפלה הסמוכה משמע לכאורה דדוקא בשוגג כמו התם שאין לה תשלומין במזיד וכמבואר בסימן ק"ח ועיין:

Loose translation:
There's a Machlokes whether we read the same parsha on the following week, in a case where they didn't read it Bemeizid (on purpose). The GR"A explains that the reason of repeating the parsha in the first place, is derived from prayers. Just like one is mashlim the prayers of one forgot to pray, so too here, we are mashlim the next week.

Therefore, just like prayers, you are only mashlim if you missed it beshogeg, so too here only if the parsha is missed beshogeg, does a Shul do it again.

---

It seems from the above, that if the vacation was done on purpose and not beshogeg, one cannot do the parsha again.

Even though this is a bit of a roundabout way to answer the question, and it doesn't answer the part about whose obligation the reading is, I believe that it still answers the main part, whether a shul can or should lain again **in your specific situation.**

Comment: You would still assume that it should be repeated if they do not agree in advance to close the synagogue for the public holiday, and the absents prevent the Torah reading?

Comment: Interesting, based on this, if you had multiple weeks in a row where a shul missed Krias Hatorah Beshogeg (not sure how a Shul would manage that, but we're dealing with theoreticals here), you still would only go back and reread the last Parshah and the current Parshah, not go back and make up all the missed ones.

Comment: Does this mean that once a shul starts, it HAS to keep going every week?   So you can never have a shul in a place where people only go for the winter or summer, since in the other seasons it won't be able to read?

Comment: @Heshy makes a very good point. Every Orthodox summer camp has a minyan there and a shul in camp. As for answering OP's situation, I'm not sure that this qualifies as "intentional". If the building is permanently there and they know in advance that they won't get a minyan no matter what, is that the "shul's fault"? What's the parameter of "intentional"? Is it specifically adbvanced planning no matter what the reason is, or is it like the shul was open but they didn't get a minyan or something happened on Shabbat itself preventing the shul from opening? (cont.)

Comment: What if there's a predicted hurricane on Shabbat and the shul decides in advance to close that week?

Comment: To all of the commentators: you all have great questions, but as i said in the last paragraph, my answer only deals with OP's specific situation. We can either wait and see if someone else will have a more general answer, or someone could write up a new question which deals with your points.