# Torah reading for foreigners in Israel on Chol HaMoed Sukkot

Tags: torah-reading, eretz-yisrael, sukkot, chutz-laaretz

The Torah reading on Chol HaMoed Sukkot is different in Israel (each day’s *mussaf* sacrifice is read four times) and the Diaspora (more than one day’s portion is read to take account of *sfeika d’yoma* (the doubt as to which day the festival actually started)).

If there is a *minyan* located in Israel but composed entirely of foreign tourists, what should they read? What if the majority are foreigners, but there is a minority of locals?

Comment: BTW do we have anything here on MY about the issue of the double portions?

Comment: Note fwiw that the Chabad custom in Israel is to read the same first three sections as outside Israel and to read the day's offering as the fourth section.

Comment: Similar: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16303/170

Comment: Are they going to Dukhen? Say two days worth in Musaf? Skip Barukh Hashem Leolam? Did they keep two day Yom Tov?

Comment: @DoubleAA All good questions. An answer to this one may answer those as well (or it may not). I think adding all of them into the question may be straying in to ‘too broad’ territory...

Comment: Seems that they should do whatever the minyan / nusach is designed for. It shouldn't matter what the majority / minority population of attendants are. It's just a decision of the rav, shamash, etc. I don't see how this would be any different from a "Galutzianer" minyan in Israel on the 2nd day of Succot or Simchat Torah (Galutzianer style) in Israel.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83371/759

Comment: @DanF What if a group of tourists in a hotel are arranging their own minyan. There isn’t really a pre-existing minhag for them to follow. You’re suggesting they should leyn chutz laaretz style? That’s definitely possible - although note that the practice of a ‘second day’ minyan in Israel is not without its detractors.

Comment: I have never stayed at an Israeli hotel since I joined a tour group as a teenager. (My Israeli relatives "spoil" me ;-) But, I would imagine that most hotels would be happy to accommodate all the tourists there for the holidays, esp. if that's a majority of their clientele. (It probably is. ) I was in Israel once during Succot and I managed to find a "Galut" minyan in a small shul in Yerushalayim. But, again, I think hotels would be the place to find them.

Comment: Similar sort of question on chanukah.